# Trying to do an inline if statement in c# with multiple options

Tags: c#, .net, if-statement

So I have two nullable decimals:

```
s.SwapProfitAmount
s.SwapProfitBps
```

Then I have a property that needs to get set to one of the values of one of these decimals called `Profit`.

What I want is an line if statement that will set `Profit` to the `Value` of whichever one of the nullable decimals that `HasValue` and has a `Value` greater than 0. If they both are 0, it will just set it to 0. Make sense?

Edit:

```
Profit
```

is a `string`.

Comment: Looks like homework... why do you need a one-liner ?

Comment: What if they are both greater than zero?  What if one or both of them has a negative value?

Comment: And why does it have to be an if statement? There are better ways here

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work. Why do you need this in a single line?

```
Profit = (s.SwapProfitAmount.HasValue && s.SwapProfitAmount.Value > 0 ? s.SwapProfitAmount.Value : s.SwapProfitBps.GetValueOrDefault(0)).ToString();
```

And for readability...

```
Profit = (
  s.SwapProfitAmount.HasValue && s.SwapProfitAmount.Value > 0
    ? s.SwapProfitAmount.Value
    : s.SwapProfitBps.GetValueOrDefault(0)
  ).ToString();
```

And since you said you were using LINQ, this might apply...

```
var results = from s in somethings
              let bps = s.SwapProfitBps.GetValueOrDefault(0)
              let amount = s.SwapProfitAmount
              let profit = amount.HasValue && amount.Value > 0
                           ? amount.Value
                           : bps
              select profit.ToString();
```

These will all fall back to SwapProfitBps when SwapProfitAmount `<= 0` or `== null`

Finally, like Andrey stated, you could just use a function...

```
Profit = GetProfitString(s);
```

Comment: I needed it on one line because this is all within a linq

Comment: @slandau this is not kind of code that should be used in production. Think about colleagues that will need to decipher it later. What prevented you from writing this logic in *normal* style in function and calling it from Linq later?

Answer (score 4):

the inline if statement is pretty simple. and if you want to nest it, the simplest way to use it and make it readable is to encase the statements in ()

```
Result = ( (evaluate Truth) ? (return if True) : (return if False));

// the result of nesting inline if statements.
MyValue = ( [statement] ? ( [another Statement] ? true : false) : ([another statement] ? false : ([another stamement] ? true : false)));
```

this however can get quite messy. and is the equivalent of actually putting the if statements.

Alternatively if they are nullable. you can do the following.

```
Profit = ((s.SwapProfitAmount.getValueOrDefault() > s.SwapProfitBps.getValueOrDefault() && s.SwapProfitAmount.HasValue) ? s.SwapProfitAmount.getValueOrDefault() : s.SwapProfitBps.getValueOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 2):

The format for the ternary operator in C# is :

```
          (condition) 
                      ? (value-if-true) 
                      : (value-if-false)
```

But, because you are only checking for a null, you can use the `coalesce` operator, which works like:

```
           (nullableObject1) ?? (nullableObject2)
```

which is equivalent to

```
           (nullableObject1 != null) ? nullableObject1 : (nullableObject2)
```

You can string these operators together, though you should use parentheses to help make your statements clear with the ternary operator.  Either approach works

Comment: Null was not the only condition he was checking for. He wanted to choose the non-null, AND non-zero value, if any.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following

```
Profit =  (s.SwapProfitAmount.HasValue && s.SwapProfitAmount.Value > 0) ? s.SwapProfitAmount.Value : (s.SwapProfitBps.HasValue && s.SwapProfitBps.Value > 0) ? s.SwapProfitBps.Value : 0) + "";
```

Comment: just added an edit. Profit is a string, so this doesn't compile, the error is Error 31 Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'string' and 'int'

Comment: actually, your answer will result to the value of "SwapProfit" even if it's zero, when it should choose the other instead.

Comment: Ah yes, I thought he meant 0 as null

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Profit =  s.SwapProfitAmount.HasValue && s.SwapProfitAmount > 0 ? 
s.SwapProfitAmount.Value.ToString() : 
s.SwapProfitBps && s.SwapProfitBps > 0 ? s.SwapProfitBps.Value.ToString() : "0";
```

Answer (score 0):

`Math.Max(s.SwapProfitAmount ?? 0, s.SwapProfitBps ?? 0)`

The problem is that you didn't mention what to do if they are both not null and > 0.

If you want string do:

`Math.Max(s.SwapProfitAmount ?? 0, s.SwapProfitBps ?? 0).ToString()`